# Sending a dot or dash when signal might get switched: Bayes' rule question

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Suppose there is some machine at the other end of a wire that sends either a “dot”or “dash” to you. The machine chooses a dot with probability $3/7$ and a dash with probability $4/7$. But as the message travels down the wire, there is a $1/8$ probability that it becomes switched: a dot becomes a dash, or a dash becomes a dot.

My question is how can I calculate $P(\text{ Dot Received}\mid \text{Dot Sent})$

I can see that it will be $\frac{7}{8}$, because conditional on sending a dot there is a $\frac{1}{8}$ chance that we don't receive a dot.

However, if I want to calculate it using $P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$, how can I know that $P(A\cap B) = \frac{3}{8}$. That is what is not obvious to me.

Thank you.

Comment: PS: It is **Bayes' Rule**, named after Thomas Bayes, so we place the apostrophe after the s.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I admit I have made that mistake before. My apologies and thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *don't* calculate $\mathsf P(A\mid B)$ from $\mathsf P(A\cap B)$.   That is trying to run the race the wrong way.

Don't try to race *to* the starting line *from* the finish line when you are already at the start and don't know where the finish even is.   Follow the track.

You are given $\mathsf P(A^\complement\mid B)$ and $\mathsf P(B)$.   That tells you $\mathsf P(A\mid B)$ and from *there* you can calculate $\mathsf P(A\cap B)$.

$$\mathsf P(A\cap B) = \mathsf P(B)~\mathsf P(A\mid B)$$

Comment: What you've said in words is correct but your last equation has a bad typo.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was looking for it to be laid out like that.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is to ask what is

$\mathsf P(\textrm{Dot sent} \mid \textrm{Dot received})$

then you need Bayesian theorem

$\mathsf P(\textrm{Dot sent} \mid \textrm{Dot received}) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(\textrm{Dot received} \mid \textrm{Dot sent})\cdot\mathrm P(\textrm{Dot sent})}{\mathsf P(\textrm{Dot received})}$

and the law of Total Probability

$\mathsf P(\textrm{Dot sent} \mid \textrm{Dot received}) = \tfrac{\mathsf P(\textrm{Dot received} \mid \textrm{Dot sent})\cdot\mathrm P(\textrm{Dot sent})}{\mathsf P(\textrm{Dot received} ~\mid~ \textrm{Dot sent})\cdot\mathrm P(\textrm{Dot sent})+\mathsf P(\textrm{Dot received} ~\mid~ \textrm{Dash sent})\cdot\mathrm P(\textrm{Dash sent})}$

Comment: Thanks, Graham, for your help!